# VSX - Is it possible to edit a already defined command/toolbar/functionality?

Tags: visual-studio, vsx

Is it possible to extend visual studio 2008/2010 to add extra options to the "Pending Window" toolwindow for Team Foundation Server?

as in

Check-In | Shelve Unshelve | **My Feature** | Workspace: foobar

Comment: I don't know the  final answer, but in VS2010, if you look at "Customize", "Commands tab", and click "Toolbar:", there are a number of items under "Context Menus|Team Foundation Server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is actually possible to place a command just about anywhere in the Visual Studio menu system. See [my answer to a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673121/how-to-extending-vs2010-editor-context-menu-for-js-file/3680427#3680427) for how you can do this.